# Why isn't Sticky Navigation Bar working through CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a portfolio website with HTML, CSS (and Bootstrap), and JavaScript. My issue is the sticky navigation bar.

The `.sticky-top` class from Bootstrap does not work. The reason it does not work is because I have a CSS line that sets overflow-x as hidden for the body. For some reason my website had a cut off in the middle and whitespace on the right side when in a mobile format, so when I looked for a solution I read to use the `overflow-x: hidden` property to fix it (shown below).

```
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Which it did fix that issue, but I was also able to isolate that this is why the navbar is not sticky. Obviously I cannot have my website cut in the middle so I thought maybe I could try another way to get a sticky navbar.

Since I can't use Bootstraps sticky nav, I tried to use `position: sticky` in CSS and that did not work either.

```
#navBar {
  position: sticky;
}
```

Then I pulled and altered multiple versions of sticky navbar code for vanilla JavaScript (including testing with `console.log` to see if they were active), and they ran but did not keep the navbar sticky.

**I am not sure how to get both the overflow-x: hidden to stay *and* get a sticky navbar.** Maybe if I could figure out how to fix the website getting cut off on mobile (therefore remove the overflow-x issue), then I would be able to keep the Bootstrap sticky-top. Does anyone have any ideas for why either are giving me trouble?

Website link: https://1amporkchop.github.io/PortfolioWebsite/

GitHub repo with all the code: https://github.com/1amporkchop/PortfolioWebsite/tree/gh-pages/docs

Answer (score 1):

you can always use `position: fixed;` make sure to also use `width: 100%;` with it